# How to run ucsc-bigwigtobedgraph using conda

Tags: conda

I have installed conda on ubuntu 22.04 and I have installed bigwigtobedgraph using

```
conda install -c bioconda ucsc-bigwigtobedgraph
```

How do I run the ucsc-bigwigtobedgraph tool? If I try and run it from the command line I get

```
ucsc-bigwigtobedgraph: command not found
```

If I type `conda list` I can see ucsc-bigwigtobedgraph is listed.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job

```
conda create --name bigwig ucsc-bigwigtobedgraph -c bioconda
```

followed by

```
conda activate bigwig
```

and then

```
bigWigToBedGraph in.bigWig out.bedGraph
```

Comment: More concisely: all the `ucsc-"toolname"` packages provide a binary `"toolname"`. Creating a new environment, while good practice, is not strictly necessary.